# postfix default alias used even when I have other aliases

Tags: alias, postfix

I tried adding a rule to /etc/aliases which would send a message to /dev/null if it was sent to a particular alias:

```
fooname: /dev/null
```

I have postfix set up with a default address for a particular domain in my /etc/postfix/virtual file:

```
@mydomain.com  realuser
```

I have multiple domains mapped to this server. I've found that if I send a message to "fooname@mydomain.com, realuser@mydomain.com, fooname@otherdomain.com, realuser@otherdomain.com" I will receive the first, second, and fourth messages, but I won't receive the third.

The upshot is that entries in /etc/aliases don't seem to short circuit the email sending.

How do I send messages for particular aliases to /dev/null while still keeping the default alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question again, but after a couple hours of struggle I figured out what to do:

First, I added the following to the main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_usernames, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

Then I added entries like the following to the access_usernames file:

```
badaddress@    REJECT
```

Then I did "postmap access_usernames" and "postfix reload".

The access_usernames file can contain any number of email addresses to reject and it seems to work fine with the default alias!